# HTTP cookies: guidelines for setting values

Tags: javascript, c#, php, asp.net, cookies

I couldn't find a clear answer to this question, hence me asking it here.  Maybe I'm just looking in the wrong places...

**What *should* I set my cookie value to?**

After reading through [RFC 6265](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt), I could only find details such as:

```
 cookie-value      = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )
 cookie-octet      = %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-3A / %x3C-5B / %x5D-7E
                   ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
                   ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
                   ; and backslash
```

and the below line makes me think I won't find any answers in that RFC:

> The semantics of the cookie-value are not defined by this document.

I'd like to know if there are any standards for what a cookie value should be?  Can it be as simple as `abc123` or should it be a really long string of random characters?

**Why?**

Comment: Making it long and seemingly random only serves the purpose of hiding information from the user, and possibly encrypting information as well, for various security reasons. If you don't see a reason to do it, you can keep your cookie values short and simple.

Comment: _Using the Set-Cookie header, a server can send the user agent a short **string** in an HTTP response that the user agent will return in future HTTP requests_ -  "String" is the keyword here. What the string should represent shouldn't matter to the HTTP protocol.

Comment: @YoryeNathan could you specify what those "various security reasons" may be?

Comment: Any reason to not handing out information, really. It's not a matter of whether it's in the cookies or not, its a matter of whether it's encrypted or not. You want to encrypt vulnerable information in endless scenarios. If you don't think information should be hidden, it probably needn't be.